# Not enough space when trying to transfer files from one HDD to another

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, transfer

Recently my hard drive started failing so I got a new one. I was copying my files to the new disc, around 350GB and around the half of the procedure - *1.5 hrs in* - it stopped without giving any message.

So decided to try and copy the files again and specify not to replace the already copied ones as to not waste 1.5 hours again and i get the message "49.0 GB more space is required to copy to the destination.", which is weird because i have 310GB free in the partition.

Gparted shows the 310GB free as well.

What is going on?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x366ec4cf

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   251660287   125829120   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       251660288   264243199     6291456   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3       264243200   515901439   125829120    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       515901440  1465147391   474622976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250263728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x637ca5d8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048     3074047     1536000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2   *     3074048  1167904767   582415360    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3      1167904768  1238264142    35179687+  83  Linux
/dev/sdb4      1238265854  1250263039     5998593    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5      1238265856  1250263039     5998592   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I'm copying from /dev/sdb2 to /dev/sda4 using nautilus @ubuntu from the live cd.

[image]

Is there a way to safely copy all the files without interruptions or issues? I can't waste any more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I had to check the size of the *folder to copy* and the *free space in the target folder*  with `du -sh` standing on each directory in the terminal.

Then `sudo rsync -asv -P /path_to_copy_from/(here will be what is copied) /path_to_copy_to/`